# Unexpected result in integration of a function

Tags: c

I try to create a program that computes the integral x<sup>x</sup> with specific limits but it seems that when I run the code the result doesn't seems right. For example, the integral of x<sup>x</sup> with limits 0 and 1 should be around 0.7834 and the result of my program shows 0.372762

Can you help me to figure the problem out?

The following code compiles with no warnings or errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    double a,b,c;
    int i;
    c=0;
    printf("Insert limit 1:");
    scanf("%lf",&a);
    printf("Insert limit 2:");
    scanf("%lf",&b);
    for( i = 0; i < ((b-a)*1000); i = i + 1 ){
      c=c+0.001*pow(a,a);
      a=a+0.001;
   }
   printf("The area is %lf", c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Because you are using an approximation, and a poor one at that. `pow` doesn't help, and it's arguments look wrong to me. Surely they should be a function of `i`? Use Simpson's rule for a polynomial of this order. I'm sure you know that there is a closed-form solution for this integral and you're merely having fun?

Comment: `the result doesn't seems right.` - can you post the result and expected result and why did you expect the expected result to happen?

Comment: You're updating one of the loop controlling variables (namely, `a`, used in the condition part of the `for`) in the loop itself. Are you 100% certain this is what you want to do?

Comment: Well, for example, the integral of x^x with limits 0 and 1 should be around 0.7834 and the result of my program shows 0.372762

Comment: Well, Kamil, I wanted in every loop value a be larger by 0.001 so in 1000 loops reach the value b

Comment: The clarification sought in @Bathsheba's comment should be edited into the question, not hidden in a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-form `for()` loop to iterate  and exact *integer* number of times.

OP's; code is changing the `a` each loop so `i < ((b - a) * 1000` does not lead to the right iteration count. [@Michail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55081244/unexpected-result-in-integration-of-a-function/55081408#comment96908438_55081244)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
  double a, b, c;
  int i;
  c = 0;
  printf("Insert limit 1:\n");
  a = 0; //scanf("%lf",&a);
  printf("Insert limit 2:\n");
  b = 1.0; /// scanf("%lf",&b);
#if 0
  for (i = 0; i < ((b - a) * 1000); i = i + 1) {
    c = c + 0.001 * pow(a, a);
    a = a + 0.001;
  }
#else
  double delta = (b - a) / 1000;
  for (i = 0; i < 1000; i = i + 1) {
    c = c + delta * pow(a, a);
    a = a + delta;
  }

#endif
  printf("The area is %lf\n", c);
  return 0;
}
```

Output

```
The area is 0.783431
```

Answer (score 1):

The loop body modifies `a` which is then re-evaluated in the `for` loop where it should be loop-invariant.  Change the loop body from:

```
  c=c+0.001*pow(a,a);
  a=a+0.001;
```

to

```
  double x = i * 0.001 ;
  c += 0.001 * pow( x, x ) ;
```

You can in fact simplify this further by using x as the loop control variable:

```
const double dx = (b - a) / 1000 ;
for( double x = a; x < b; x += dx )
{
    c += 0.001 * pow( x, x ) ;
}
```

Further the multiplication by 0.001 on each iteration is unnecessary; you can apply that after the loop to the same effect and in some cases less accumulated error.

```
const double dx = (b - a) / 1000 ;
for( double x = a; x < b; x += dx )
{
    c += pow( x, x ) ;
}
c *= dx  ;
```

So the complete code becomes:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() 
{
    double a = 0 ;
    double b = 1.0 ;
    printf( "Enter limit 1:");
    scanf(  "%lf", &a ) ;
    printf( "Enter limit 2:");
    scanf( "%lf", &b ) ;

    const double dx = (b - a) / 1000 ;
    double c = 0 ;
    for( double x = a; x < b; x += dx )
    {
        c += pow( x, x ) ;
    }
    c *= dx  ;

    printf( "The area is %lf", c )  ;
    return 0;
}
```

Example:

```
Enter limit 1:0                                                                                                                                          
Enter limit 2:1                                                                                                                                          
The area is 0.783431
```